# ionViewCanEnter In Components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Interesting issue I’ve run into: when including a component or page in another page it seems that ionViewCanEnter isn’t firing. If you access a page directly, it’ll fire, but including it in another page using its selector causes it not to fire. I tried making a component and including that in a page and it’s not working. I need a special view on two pages and, trying to reuse code, decided to move my code to a component and include that in both pages, but the issue is that the HTML template calls a function and that function requires some async data before it can respond so I need to have the view held back until I receive that data. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here’s my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the PageStylesComponent component.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Component for more info on Angular
 * Components.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'page-styles',
  templateUrl: 'page-styles.html'
})
export class PageStylesComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello PageStylesComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

  ionViewCanEnter(): boolean | Promise<any> {
    return this.auth();
  }

  auth() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

}
```

HTML for component:

{{text}}
I have this imported to another page as so:

```
<ion-col col-4>
  <page-styles></page-styles>   
</ion-col>
```

When running this other page, I get Hello World printed immediately. Further, console does not show that the ionViewCanEnter is fired. I get:

Hello PageStylesComponent Component
ionViewDidLoad EditStylesPage (The other page)

But no ionViewCanEnter from my component. I’ve been doing tons of research and can’t find a solution.

CLI Info:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
Node              : v8.10.0
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000 
Misc:

backend : pro
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Add `@ViewChild` so you can access the component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-page',
    templateURL: 'parent-page.html'
})
export class ParentPage{
    @ViewChild('myComponent') myComponent;

    constructor(){}

    ionViewCanEnter(){
        this.myComponent.someFunc();
    }

    ...
}
```

and

```
<ion-content>
    ...
    <child-component #myComponent></child-component>
    ...
</ion-content>
```

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

> Navigating from the Root component What if you want to control
>   navigation from your root app component? You can't inject
>   NavController because any components that are navigation controllers
>   are children of the root component so they aren't available to be
>   injected.
>
> By adding a reference variable to the ion-nav, you can use @ViewChild
>   to get an instance of the Nav component, which is a navigation
>   controller (it extends NavController). - [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)